# Can't get filter criteria from DataSourceSheet using Google Apps Script: getHiddenValues() method returns empty result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I expect `filter.getFilterCriteria().getHiddenValues()` to return a list of those values that are responsible for displaying the data in the columns (for example the column "cargo" contains many different values, I have configured the filter on the sheet to display only those rows where "cargo" contains "cargo name 1", therefore I would like to get "cargo name 1" using this method)

However, `filter.getFilterCriteria().getHiddenValues()` returns empty. Although `sheet.getFilters()` returns the "cargo" column as a column containing some kind of filter. I checked the filter type of this column with `filter.getFilterCriteria().getCriteriaType()`, the type is null.

How can I solve this problem and get the filter criteria correctly? Here is a sample of my code:

```
function labExport(){
  SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Orders').asDataSourceSheet();
  const filters = sheet.getFilters();
  for (var filter of filters){
    const columnName = filter.getDataSourceColumn().getName();
    const criteriaValues = JSON.stringify(filter.getFilterCriteria().getCriteriaValues());
    const hiddenValues = JSON.stringify(filter.getFilterCriteria().getHiddenValues());

    Logger.log(`${columnName} has filter. \n
    -- Filter type is ${filter.getFilterCriteria().getCriteriaType()}. \n
    -- Filter criteria is: \n
    --- getCriteriaValues: ${criteriaValues} \n
    --- getHiddenValues: ${hiddenValues}`);
  }
}
```

```
Logs:

 19:48:34   Information     
 cargo has filter.
 -- Filter type is null.      
 -- Filter criteria is:     
 --- getCriteriaValues: []  
 --- getHiddenValues: []

 19:48:34   Information     
 date has filter.
 -- Filter type is DATE_AFTER.      
 -- Filter criteria is:     
 --- getCriteriaValues: ["2023-08-26T21:00:00.000Z"]    
 --- getHiddenValues: []
```

From the log, you can see that both cargo and date have some filtering. But if we can get the criterion from date without any problems, we don't understand anything at all with cargo. Google documentation does not say anything clear about the methods I use.

I have an idea that maybe when we get criteria for cargo, the script fires faster than it can get filters. I have this idea because when we select filters, or just view them in DataSourceSheet, we always have to wait a bit until all the unique values in a given column are loaded (there are only about 1 million rows in the source database). But I don't fully understand how I can test this hypothesis and what corrections I need to make in the code to make it work.

Comment: `have configured the filter on the sheet to display only those rows where "cargo" contains "cargo name 1"` Screenshot or gif please

Comment: We assign filters to a column on the data source sheet and output only those records that contain values (checked in the third screenshot). And it is these criteria that GAS does not have access to.

I simplified the description of the situation a bit when I wrote the task. In fact, it looks like this (I apologize that everything is in Russian, since our interfaces are the same, I think you should understand what's going on here): 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HMm2hW164gal_6k_cS9i7o4fPcv3PrwA?usp=drive_link - here are screenshots

Comment: By the way, now tried to get such criteria even through `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[0].basicFilter`, in the response I get all the same result as in the description, but in the form: `{filterSpecs=[{filterSpecs={}, dataSourceCriteria={}, dataSourceColumnReference={name=cargo}}, {filterCriteria={}, dataSourceColumnReference={name=date}}, {filterCriteria={condition={type=DATE_AFTER, values=[{userEnteredValue=27.08. 2023}]}},...`

Comment: Try checking the returned json using Try this API  [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#basicfilter)

Comment: Already tried it, same result. when I use `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[0].basicFilter.filterSpecs`, I get:  
`{filterCriteria={condition={values=[{userEnteredValue=27.08.2023}], type=DATE_AFTER}}, dataSourceColumnReference={name=date}},  
{dataSourceColumnReference={name=cargo}, filterCriteria={}},  
...`  

`Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[0].basicFilter.criteria`  
Log: `null`

`Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[0].basicFilter.sortSpecs`  
Log: `[{dataSourceColumnReference={name=date}, sortOrder=ASCENDING}]`

Comment: 1. Try getting sheet without datasource sheet.... `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Orders')` and getting fiters of that class .2. Also, if you manually deselect some values in `date` column. Do those show up in data sourcefilters hidden values? 3. To be clear, you manually unselected some values in `cargo` column correct?

Comment: 1. Exception: The action is not supported for DATASOURCE sheet. Please use getFilters method on DataSourceSheet obtained by Sheet.asDataSourceSheet().   2. No, they don't. Only the criteria that I enter manually are displayed.   3. Yes, that's right. But I did not manually write conditions for cargo, but selected some values from the list of values by clicking on them (you can see it on screenshot 3).

Comment: I think it's better to create a issue directly in Google issue tracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for link

Comment: Having said that, the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria#gethiddenvalues) do say that `getHiddenValues()` returns `null`, when the sheet is not a `Grid` sheet(Connected sheet is a `DataSource` sheet). But it returning empty array instead of `null` seems inconsistent with the documentation.

Comment: Next week I'll try to contact pass the info to google issue tracker, nevertheless thank you so much for trying to help.